# Find parameters in an algorithm with Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I work on an equalization project. I've implemented the Least Mean Squares (LMS) algorithm with a set of data. To initialize coefficients *h*: *h[k+1] = h[k] + mu e[k] x[k]*.

I need to find a compromize between the time to converge and the final Mean Squared Error (MSE) by adjusting the convergence parameter *mu*.

I would like to know if there is an AI which could find the parameter *mu*. Something not complicated to implement (I don't have a huge background on AI/ML).

Thanks in advance.